# How do I update a website custom property in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I have some code which does the following:

```
const string KEY_CHK = "Microsoft.IW.PartCheck";
SPWeb curWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
if (!curWeb.Properties.ContainsKey(KEY_CHK))
{ 
   curWeb.Properties.Add(KEY_CHK, "true");
   curWeb.Properties.Update();
}
```

This runs as a webpart in a master page in Sharepoint 2007.

I would like to be able to update the value of a property in a non-code way.
Through Sharepoint admin screens, or via Sharepoint designer.

Is this possible? Where/how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using SharePoint Manager 2007 from http://www.codeplex.com/spm.

.b

Answer (score 0):

nope, you cannot set web properties via the UI.  maybe there's something on CodePlex

Answer (score 0):

you could try the propertybag manager. It adds a page to your central admin from where you can inspect and edit properties from all bags:

http://pbs.codeplex.com/